# How can I convert a normal javascript code to angular component specific code which uses event handling

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, netflix

I am trying to convert a javascript code that handles events related to tabs on a page, i.e. whenever a user clicks on a particular tab a red border should appear underneath it (Just like how the Netflix landing page website works). But I am getting an error when pasting the same code in my landing page component typescript file. I am providing the landing.component.html, landing.component.css, landing.component.ts and the javascript file (main.js) which I want to convert.

landing.component.html

```
<header class="showcase">
<div class="showcase-top">
    <img src="../../assets/logo.png" alt="Netflix">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-rounded">Sign In</a>
</div>
<div class="showcase-content">
    <h1>See what's next</h1>
    <p>Watch anywhere. Cancel anytime</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xl">
        Watch Free for 30 Days <i class="fas fa-chevron-right btn-icon"></i>
    </a>
</div>
</header>
<section class="tabs">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-item tab-border">
        <i class="fas fa-door-open fa-3x"></i>
        <p class="hide-sm">Cancel Anytime</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-item">
        <i class="fas fa-tablet-alt fa-3x"></i>
        <p class="hide-sm">Watch Anywhere</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-item">
        <i class="fas fa-tags fa-3x"></i>
        <p class="hide-sm">Pick your price</p>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<section class="tab-content">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Tab 1 Content -->
    <div id="tab-1-content" class="tab-content-item show">
        <div class="tab-1-content-inner">
            <div>
                <p class="text-lg">
                   If you decide Netflix isn't for you- no problem. 
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg">Watch Free For 30 Days</a>
            </div>
            <img src="../../assets/tab-content-1.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Tab 2 Content -->
    <div id="tab-2-content" class="tab-content-item">
        <div class="tab-2-content-top">
            <p class="text-lg">
                If you decide Netflix isn't for you.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg">Watch Free For 30 Days</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-2-content-bottom">
            <div>
                <img src="../../assets/tab-content-2-1.png" alt="">
                <p class="text-md">Watch on your TV</p>
                <p class="text-dark">Smart TVs, PlayStation, Xbox, Chromecast, Apple TV, Blu-ray players and more.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="../../assets/tab-content-2-2.png" alt="">
                <p class="text-md">Watch instantly or download for later</p>
                <p class="text-dark">Available on phone and tablet, wherever you go.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="../../assets/tab-content-2-3.png" alt="">
                <p class="text-md">Use any computer</p>
                <p class="text-dark">Watch right on Netflix.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Tab 3 Content -->
    <div id="tab-3-content" class="tab-content-item">
        <div class="text-center">
            <p class="text-lg">Choose one plan and watch everything on Netflix</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg">Watch Free For 30 Days</a>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Basic</th>
                    <th>Standard</th>
                    <th>Premium</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Monthly price after free month ends on 6/19/20</td>
                    <td>$8.99</td>
                    <td>$12.99</td>
                    <td>$15.99</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>HD Available</td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-times"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ultra HD Available</td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-times"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-times"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Screens you can watch on at the same time</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Watch on your laptop, TV, phone and tablet</td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Unlimited movies and TV shows</td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cancel anytime</td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First month free</td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<footer class="footer">
<p>Questions? Call 1-866-576-7172</p>
<div class="footer-cols">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Investor Relations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ways To Watch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Corporate Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Netflix Originals</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Help Center</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Terms Of Use</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Redeem Gift Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Speed Test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Media Center</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Buy Gift Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cookie Preferences</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Legal Notices</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</footer>
```

loading.component.css

```
.showcase{
width: 100% !important;
height: 93vh !important;
position: relative !important;
background: url('../../assets/background.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover !important;
}

.showcase::after{
content: '' !important;
position: absolute !important;
top: 0 !important;
left: 0 !important;
width: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
z-index: 1 !important;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6) !important;
box-shadow: inset 120px 100px 250px #000000, inset -120px -100px 250px #000000 !important;
}

.showcase-top{
position: relative !important;
z-index: 2 !important;
height: 90px !important;
}

.showcase-top img{
width: 170px !important;
position: absolute !important;
top: 50% !important;
left: 50% !important;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}

.showcase-top a{
position: absolute !important;
top: 50% !important;
right: 0 !important;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}

.showcase-content{
position: relative !important;
z-index: 2 !important;
margin: auto !important;
display: flex !important;
flex-direction: column !important;
justify-content: center !important;
align-items: center !important;
text-align: center !important;
margin-top: 9rem !important;
}

.showcase-content h1{
font-weight: 700 !important;
font-size: 5.2rem !important;
line-height: 1.1 !important;
margin: 0 0 2rem !important;
}

.showcase-content p{
text-transform: uppercase !important;
color: #fff !important;
font-weight: 400 !important;
font-size: 1.9rem !important;
line-height: 1.25 !important;
margin: 0 0 2rem !important;
}

/* Tabs */
.tabs{
background: var(--dark-color) !important;
padding-top: 1rem !important;
border-bottom: 3px solid #3d3d3d !important;
}

.tabs .container-fluid{
display: grid !important;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) !important;
grid-gap: 1rem !important;
align-items: center !important;
justify-content: center !important;
text-align: center !important;
}

.tabs p{
font-size: 1.2rem !important;
padding-top: 0.5rem !important;
}

.tabs .container-fluid > div{
padding: 1.5rem 0 !important;
}

.tabs .container-fluid > div:hover{
color: #fff !important;
cursor: pointer !important;
}

.tab-border{
border-bottom: var(--primary-color) 4px solid !important;
}

/* Tab Content */
.tab-content{
padding: 3rem 0 !important;
background: #000 !important;
color: #fff !important;
}

/* Hide Content Initially */
#tab-1-content,
#tab-2-content,
#tab-3-content{
display: none !important;
}

.tab-content-item .show{
display: block !important;
}

#tab-1-content .tab-1-content-inner{
display: grid !important;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr) !important;
grid-gap: 2rem !important;
align-items: center !important;
justify-content: center !important;
}

#tab-2-content .tab-2-content-top{
display: grid !important;
grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr !important;
grid-gap: 1rem !important;
justify-content: center !important;
align-items: center !important;
}

#tab-2-content .tab-2-content-bottom{
margin-top: 2rem !important;
display: grid !important;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) !important;
grid-gap: 2rem !important;
justify-content: center !important;
align-items: center !important;
text-align: center !important;
}

.table{
width: 100% !important;
margin-top: 2rem !important;
border-collapse: collapse !important;
border-spacing: 0 !important;
}

.table thead th{
text-transform: uppercase !important;
padding: 0.8rem !important;
color: #fff !important;
border: none !important;
}

.table tbody tr td{
color: #999 !important;
padding: 0.8rem 1.2rem !important;
text-align: center !important;
border: none !important;
}

.table tbody tr td:first-child{
text-align: left !important;
}

.table tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
background: #222 !important;
}

/* Footer */
.footer{
max-width: 75% !important;
margin: 1rem auto !important;
overflow: auto !important;
}

.footer, .footer a{
color: #999 !important;
font-size: 0.9rem !important;
}

.footer p{
margin-bottom: 1.5rem !important;
}

.footer .footer-cols{
display: grid !important;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr) !important;
grid-gap: 2rem !important;
}

.footer li{
line-height: 1.9 !important;
}

/* Container */
.container-fluid{
max-width: 70% !important;
margin: auto !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
padding: 0 2rem !important;
}

/* Text Styles */
.text-xl{
font-size: 2rem !important;
margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
}

.text-lg{
font-size: 1.8rem !important;
margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
}

.text-md{
font-size: 1.5rem !important;
margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
}

.text-center{
text-align: center !important;
}

.text-dark{
color: #999 !important;
}

/* Buttons */
.btn{
display: inline-block !important;
background: var(--primary-color) !important;
color: #fff !important;
padding: 0.4rem 1.3rem !important;
font-size: 1rem !important;
text-align: center !important;
border: none !important;
cursor: pointer !important;
margin-right: 0.5rem !important;
outline: none !important;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.45) !important;
border-radius: 2px !important;
}

.btn:hover{
opacity: 0.9 !important;
}

.btn-rounded{
border-radius: 5px !important;
}

.btn-xl{
font-size: 2rem !important;
padding: 1.5rem 2.1rem !important;
text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

.btn-lg{
font-size: 1rem !important;
padding: 0.8rem 1.3rem !important;
text-transform: uppercase !important;
}


@media(max-width: 960px){
.showcase{
    height: 70vh !important;
}

.hide-sm{
    display: none !important;
}

.showcase-top img{
    top: 30% !important;
    left: 5% !important;
    transform: translate(0) !important;
}

.showcase-content h1{
    font-size: 3.7rem !important;
    line-height: 1 !important;
}

.showcase-content p{
    font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}

.footer .footer-cols{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr) !important;
}

.btn-xl{
    font-size: 1.5rem !important;
    padding: 1.4rem 2rem !important;
}

.text-xl{
    font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}

.text-lg{
    font-size: 1.3rem !important;
}

.text-md{
    font-size: 1rem !important;
}
}

@media(max-width: 700px){
.showcase::after{
    box-shadow: inset 80px 80px 250px #000000, inset -80px -80px 250px #000000 !important;
}

#tab-1-content .tab-1-content-inner{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr !important;
    text-align: center !important;        
}

#tab-2-content .tab-2-content-top{
    display: block !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}

#tab-2-content .tab-2-content-bottom{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr !important;
}
}
```

landing.component.ts (I am getting the error in this file)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

const tabItems = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-item');
const tabContentItems = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content-item');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing',
  templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing.component.css']
})

export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {}

// Select tab content item
function selectItem(){
removeBorder();
// Add border to current tab
this.classList.add('tab-border');
}

function removeBorder(){
tabItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('tab-border'));
}

// Listen for tab click
tabItems.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', selectItem));

}
```

main.js (This is the code I want in landing.component.ts)

```
const tabItems = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-item');
const tabContentItems = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content-item');

// Select tab content item
function selectItem(e){
removeBorder();
// Add border to current tab
this.classList.add('tab-border');
}

function removeBorder(){
tabItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('tab-border'));
}

// Listen for tab click
tabItems.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', selectItem));
```

P.S. I have been following a tutorial series to make this. The link is: [Build a Netflix Landing Page Clone with HTML, CSS & JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7t13SGytRk&t=4907s)

The source code for the tutorial is in the link: [Source Code](https://codepen.io/bradtraversy/pen/yWPONg)

Please suggest the corrections to be made in the typescript file

Comment: and add source code of angular app in https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the possibilities of angular,

Look how I did it [your landing in angular](https://angular-hjwpfd.stackblitz.io/)

What I've done:

In app.component.ts add tabs array, variable activeTabId, and function selectTab():

```
tabs = [
  {id: 1, title: 'Cancel at any time'},
  {id: 2, title: 'Watch anywhere'},
  {id: 3, title: 'Pick your price'}
];
activeTabId = this.tabs[0].id;

selectTab(tab) {
  this.activeTabId = tab.id;
}
```

And change Template(HTML), adding tabs array dynamic, and add class, id dynamic.

```
<section class="tabs">
<div class="container">
    <div class="tab-item" *ngFor="let tab of tabs;" [attr.id]="'tab-'+tab?.id"
        [ngClass]="{'tab-border': activeTabId === tab?.id}" (click)="selectTab(tab)">
        <i class="fas fa-door-open fa-3x"></i>
        <p class="hide-sm">Cancel at any time</p>
    </div>
    <!--
            <div id="tab-2" class="tab-item">
                <i class="fas fa-tablet-alt fa-3x"></i>
                <p class="hide-sm">Watch anywhere</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tab-3" class="tab-item">
                <i class="fas fa-tags fa-3x"></i>
                <p class="hide-sm">Pick your price</p>
            </div>
    -->
</div>
```

And when clicked selectTab(), in template use NgSwitch, to switch between tabs:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="activeTabId">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1" id="tab-1-content">...</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="2" id="tab-2-content">...</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="3" id="tab-3-content">...</div>
</ng-container>
```

And the code link [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjwpfd)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop the items and add addEventListener kind of thing in angular.
Add the click event in the tab item in html itself like below.

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-item tab-border" (click)="selectItem($event)">
   <i class="fas fa-door-open fa-3x"></i>
   <p class="hide-sm">Cancel Anytime</p>
</div>
```

And Remove the below lines from your ts file.

```
// Listen for tab click
tabItems.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', selectItem));
```